# useEffect dependency causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I created a custom hook which I use in App.js

The custom hook (relevant function is fetchTasks):

```
export default function useFetch() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const fetchTasks = async (url) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("falied!");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const loadedTasks = [];
      for (const taskKey in data) {
        loadedTasks.push({ id: taskKey, text: data[taskKey].text });
      }

      setTasks(loadedTasks);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return {
    loading,
    setLoading,
    error,
    setError,
    fetchTasks,
    tasks,
  };
}
```

Then in my App.js:

```
function App() {
  const { loading, setLoading, error, setError, fetchTasks, tasks } =
    useFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching");
    fetchTasks(
      "https://.....firebaseio.com/tasks.json"
    );
  }, []);
```

My IDE suggests adding the fetchTasks function as a dependency to useEffect. But once I add it, an infinite loop is created. If I omit it from the dependencies as shown in my code, it will work as expected, but I know this is a bad practice. What should I do then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: The reason it creates an infinite loop is that every time you call `useFetch` you create a new function called `fetchTasks`, so the reference changes at every render.  Instead you can leverage [the `useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) [as referenced in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327893/6831341) to memoize your `fetchTasks` function so the reference remains unchanged at each usage of your `useFetch` hook.

Comment: I understand now thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that every time you call `useFetch()`. `fetchTasks` function will be re-created. That cause the reference to change at every render then `useEffect()` will detected that dependency `fetchTasks` is re-created and execute it again, and make the infinite loop.
So you can leverage `useCallback()` to memoize your `fetchTasks()` function so the reference will remains unchanged.

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'

export default function useFetch() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const fetchTasks = useCallback(
    async (url) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("falied!");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const loadedTasks = [];
      for (const taskKey in data) {
        loadedTasks.push({ id: taskKey, text: data[taskKey].text });
      }

      setTasks(loadedTasks);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };,[])

  return {
    loading,
    setLoading,
    error,
    setError,
    fetchTasks,
    tasks,
  };
}
```

```
function App() {
  const { loading, setLoading, error, setError, fetchTasks, tasks } =
    useFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching");
    fetchTasks(
      "https://.....firebaseio.com/tasks.json"
    );
  }, [fetchTasks]);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of return `fetchTasks` function return this `useCallback` `fetchTasksCallback` function from `useFetch` hook which created only one instance of `fetchTasksCallback`.

```
const fetchTasksCallback = useCallback(
  (url) => {
    fetchTasks(url);
  },
  [],
);
```

```
function App() {
  const { loading, setLoading, error, setError, fetchTasksCallback, tasks } =
    useFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching");
    fetchTasksCallback(
      "https://.....firebaseio.com/tasks.json"
    );
  }, [fetchTasksCallback]);
```

the problem is this `fetchTasks` every time create a new instance that way dependency list feels that there is a change and repeats the `useEffect` code block which causes the infinite loop problem